# a simple standard belief propagation

Tags: propagation, belief-propagation

I read Zhang's paper [**Expert Finding in A Social Network**](http://keg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/jietang/publications/Zhang-et-al-Expert-Finding.pdf), formula(1) is a propagation-base approach,similar to a standard belief propagation.Is there a code example or tool to do this? the propagation scheduler seems need to be a parallel implementation.Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right site for this. Also you need better tags if you want anyone to notice this question. (If the tags don't exist, it's probably because this isn't the right site.)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [LibDai](http://www.libdai.org) (open source, based on C++ and MatLab) which provides some inference algorithms, including some variations of the belief propagation.

Comment: Hi @Alex I'm not familiar with BP, which BP fits me?

Comment: That's a question completely different from the original one, and that should be asked on math.stackexchange.com